# Problema background CSS web

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué me sale entre el primer y segundo elemento de mi web (div) sin el espacio en blanco si tengo el fondo transparente o un background blanco?

Os dejo mi web: http://www.osmarentcars.esy.es/

Os dejo mi código CSS:

```
*{
    margin-top:  4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}


#todo{
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 14;
    margin: auto;
    background: transparent; //esto tendría que hacer efecto...
}


div{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}


img{
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    height: 60px;

}


.columna{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.descripcion{
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Voto la pregunta para cierre por "error tipográfico o que no se puede reproducir". En tu página web no tienes el código que muestras aquí debido a que tu div `#todo` no tiene ningún tipo de background y lo toma del elemento div (azul). ¿El porque te aparece solo entre el primer y segundo div? En realidad es pura casualidad y se debe a que tienes una altura para el div `#todo` que ocupa 100px, por lo tanto, solo engloba el primer elemento y una parte del segundo. Te recomiendo quitar la altura al div `#todo` para que englobe a todos los elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene porque el contenedor que utilizas (#todo) también tiene de fondo el color azul pues lo aplicas a todos los DIV y no se está aplicando la propiedad background de #todo. Cambiala por:
background-color: transparent

Editado: con background debería funcionar (he hecho la prueba), asegúrate de que el css del servidor esté actualizado con la configuración indicada pues el que se descarga el navegador no aparece dicha propiedad.
http://www.osmarentcars.esy.es/estilos.css